# Xcode 11.4 - Disappeared iOS simulator features -> location freeway drive option

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

After updating to latest Xcode and macOS version disappeared option of simulating freeway drive.
Simulator -> Features -> Location -> 2 options:

- None
- Custom location

How to get freeway drive option back, please help. Thank a lot.

[image]

Comment: it was a known issue in Xcode 11.4 Beta 3 release - "The Location menu does not show any location simulation scenarios. (59334531) (FB7572832)". Currently this issue is not listed in release notes, but still exist in stable version. Xcode is so Xcode.

Comment: September 2020 and the problem persists. Sometimes I think Apple just wants us to give them up.